# Corner radius not showing on button in storyboard with @IBDesigable/@IBInspectable

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistoryboard, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have this custom class for a button.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusValue: CGFloat = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setUpView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

}
```

But the corner radius is not showing on the button in the storyboard.

I understand @IBInspectable just allows you to change the value in the inspector panel. I guess thats not what I am looking for.

I would like the corner radius to just show in storyboard when I create a button with that class. Which I thought that's what @IBDesignable does.

Comment: Don't know if it will solve but you're not clipping the layer to its bounds which you probably need to do in order for it to display at least at runtime. Not sure about in storyboard

Comment: Added that and didnt fix what I wanted. Thank you though.

Comment: The problem is that your code is crashing in IB so designability fails. I've provided a version of your code that doesn't crash, so it works as expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is crashing in IB, so designability fails. Here is much simpler code that works:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusValue: CGFloat = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUpView()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setUpView()
    }
    func setUpView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadiusValue
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Now the button is both inspectable and designable:

[image]

And it also works in the running app.

Comment: Can you specify how my answer was wrong? as you have said : "Did you actually try this? Did it round the corners in the storyboard?"

Comment: was very useful that you call `setUpView()` on didSet rather on init of the class. that solved the trick. Thanks.

Comment: You can just call `setNeedsDisplay()` in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`, remove the implementation of `awakeFromNib()`, and have the logic of updating the corner radius be directly in `didSet`.

Comment: If you want to set the layer border width, you should create a separate value for it, just like the corner radius. Setting the corner radius should not modify other properties. That would be misleading and leads to spaghetti code. It would violate the principle called orthogonality.

Comment: Your answer sets clipsToBounds in the property observer. It just obfuscates it a little. `cornerRadiusValue` is an unnecessarily redundant name. `setUpView` is a misleading name. Your answer adds unnecessary state by using a stored property.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better solution than the accepted answer:

```
@IBDesignable
class DesignableButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable private var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

}
```

It uses a computed property to avoid duplicating state with a stored property.