# TextView Border Color and Border Radius Not Set

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I want to set corner Radius of `UITextView` By Interface . But I am unable to do this . This code Work Fine for `UILabel`, `UIButton` but give error in `UITextView` 
Intializer does not override a designated intializer from superclass.

```
class MyText: UITextView {
        @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
            didSet {
                layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            }
        }


        @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
            didSet {
                layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            }
        }

        @IBInspectable var cornurRadius: CGFloat = 1.0 {
            didSet {
                layer.cornerRadius = cornurRadius
                clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }

        //MARK: Initializers
        override init(frame : CGRect) {
            super.init(frame : frame)
            setup()
            configure()
        }

        convenience init() {
            self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
            setup()
            configure()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            setup()
            configure()
        }


        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            setup()
            configure()
        }

        override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
            super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
            setup()
            configure()
        }

        func setup() {
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            layer.cornerRadius = 1.0
        }

        func configure() {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            layer.cornerRadius = cornurRadius
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }

    }
```

Comment: in setup method write this. `clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set rounded corner for a UITextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922986/how-to-set-rounded-corner-for-a-uitextview)

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Add `@IBDesignable` above class declaraion

Comment: Not working Sir....

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759138/corner-radius-not-showing-on-button-in-storyboard-with-ibdesigable-ibinspectab

Comment: @LoVo Its working Sir.. Thanku Sir

Comment: Welcome, don`t forget to vote up matt's answer. Because he solved your problem